# OSX - Get File Path from FileURL from Drag and Drop with Sandboxed application

Tags: objective-c, macos, drag-and-drop, sandbox

I am Using Drag and Drop to drop a File onto my APP.

Apple deprecated  NSFilenamesPboardType in OSX 10.14 and suggests using NSPasteboardTypeFileURL.

The URL(String) I get is:

> file:///.file/id=6571367.2682325

How do I get the Actual File Path from this URL ? 
I need File Name and Type info.
Can I also access the File with the Full File Path ? I assume it is added to my Sandbox.

Answer (score 1):

I'm working at Mac OS 10.14 with Xcode 10.2.

I got two solutions in performDragOperation (both registerForDraggedTypes with NSPasteboardTypeFileURL. Then):

1. mentioned above

   [[NSURL URLWithString:relativePath] fileSystemRepresentation];
2. init pasteBoard

   NSString *fileURL = [[NSURL URLFromPasteboard:pasteBoard] path];

Comment: This is the answer for a local path. An NSURL using the file protocol with an ID, will be correctly converted to a readable path string with the @(path) selector. It's not obvious but it does work.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution using:

```
NSURL * url = [NSURL initWithString:urlString];
NSString * path = [url fileSystemRepresentation];
```

And yes the file was accessible from my Sandboxed application.